# No .app bundles found in the package

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Im uploading my application using the itunes connect online tool. I get this error saying "No .app bundles found in the package". What is wrong?

Comment: @trojanfoe Obviously you have no idea what im talking about!

Comment: Obviously none of us can have any idea of what you are talking about because (again) obviously we can't know what are you exactly doing! Where does that file or whatever comes from what you want to upload? What are you exactly trying to upload, in what format? Also, Apple has tons of docs about iTunes Connect and its upload process.

Comment: @Rickye Ok im sorry i havnt made myself clear this has been giving me a headache for the past two days. Im using Application Loader to upload my application. I zipped the whole project. I get this error in the middle of the application load process.

Comment: You shouldn't zip the whole project, because it only contains the code and not the binary itself. (To make it clear, Apple won't compile it for you, you have to do it.) [Follow this tutorial's 'Submitting with Xcode' section to find an easier and working way to submit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)

Comment: @Rickye Ok so if i want to upload it with iTunes Connect, what kind of file format should i provide? I am really confused here.

Comment: You should provide the compiled .app bundle, not the source.

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem developing my apps in XCode 7.3.1 with OS X El Capitan and then update to macOS Sierra and Xcode 8.

I can solve this problem following the next steps:

1. Archive your app with Xcode 7.3.1 (download in developer.apple.com)
2. When you archived your app, find your archive in the Organizer, and then:

"Show in finder";

"Show package contents";

In the "xx.xcarchive" file, find the "Products"-"Applications"-"xx.app"(xx is your app's name), "Show package contents" again;

Finally, you can see there has a file named"Info.plist", 
open it;

Edit the value with a key named "BuildMachineOSBuild", I just change it to "16A323"(it's "macOS Sierra" 's version);

Edit the value with a key named "DTXcodeBuild" with the Xcode 8 version number "8A218a"

After that, you can upload this archive use Xcode 8 or Application Loader in macOS Sierra, whatever you want!

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX6lB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably zipping your bundle before build completion

Answer (score 0):

I got that message when i tried to archive the App with my hard drive full. (less than 500mo).
I free some space on my drive and it validate successfully.